# How to sample an IObservable<T> with a ReactiveCommand

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a source observable

```
Observable<T> source
```

and an execution function

```
void Execute(T t){
    ....
}
```

I wish to write a ReactiveCommand that executes T with the latest value of source when triggered. The command should not be executable when no value is available

Answer (score 2):

```
/// Create a ReactiveCommand that samples a source observable. The
/// source is immediately subscribed to so that when the command
/// is executed the previous value is available to the execution
/// function.

public static ReactiveCommand<Unit,Unit> CreateCommand<T>
    (this IObservable<T> source
     , Action<T> execute
     , IObservable<bool> canExecute)
{
    var so = source.Replay(1).RefCount();

    return ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask
        ( async () => execute( await so.FirstAsync() )
          , canExecute.Merge( so.Select( _ => true ).StartWith( true ) ));
}
```

Usage

```
IObservable<int> dataSource = ...;
IObservable<bool> canExecute = ...;
ReactiveCommand command = ReactiveCommandCreate
      ( dataSource
      , value => Console.WriteLine(value)
      , canExecute
      );
```

Comment: This should be in question itself.

Comment: No. It is the solution. I was writing the question and then figured out the solution. No reason not to post both together. If you have a better solution then feel free to add one. I might like yours better. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, I think it can be quite a bit simpler with a behavior subject and something to watch for that first value.

```
var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
var subject = new BehaviorSubject<long>(0L);
source.Subscribe(subject);
var canExecute = source.Select(_ => true).StartWith(false);
ICommand command = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => Execute(subject.Value), canExecute);
```

Comment: You now have two subscriptions to dispose instead of just one. If you wrap it into a function that returns just the command you then need to find a way to dispose of the subject. I gave you a point anyway :)

Comment: Absolutely. The responsible thing to do would be to wrap it all up in a `CompositeDisposable`.

Comment: Or just tie the lifetime of the subject subscription to the command with `Observable.Using()`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229585(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: It's not quite as simple as you make out. In my answer I've cheated by tying the subscription of the source observable to canExecute. This will ensure that the source is subscribed to when the command is created and unsubscribed when the command is disposed. I only need to return the command from the utility function.